# How to bind Items to ItemsSource?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

I want to show myElement.ContextMenu icons in separate panel.
I'm trying to do this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=myElement, Path=ContextMenu.ItemsSource}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Image Source="{Binding Icon}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

But it shows me collection of MenuItems instead of Images. How can I do it without any ViewModels and manipulations in xxx.xaml.cs file.

Comment: provide the XAML for myElement (what is ContextMenu.ItemsSource)

Comment: ContextMenu is context menu of any FrameworkElement. It doesn't have any special code. Just collection of MenuItems.

Comment: What happens if you ommit DataType property?

Comment: If you set your MenuItems in XAML, then ItemsSource would be null, wouldn't it? Maybe you should write Path=ContextMenu.Items

Comment: I've tried it. It have the same effect. BTW, it shows items. But I need in other types of items.

Comment: I guess that this should work...

Comment: Yeah, it should work, but it doesn't, so I've posted question on this forum.

Comment: What happens if you replace the `Image` control in your data template by a `ContentControl` with `Content={Binding Icon}`?

Comment: Same result ((( I think it ignores DataTemplate...

Comment: Post the XAML for your myElement, that should help us solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are binding to `ContextMenu.ItemsSource` which is a different property than `ContextMenu.Items`

`ItemsSource` will only be set if you set it to something, such as a collection of objects, and if that is the case then your `ItemsControl` will also be bound to the same collection of objects. Unless the list of objects used in your `ItemsSource` is bound to has a property called `Icon`, your code will not work.

If you try to bind to `ContextMenu.Items`, you will get a collection of `MenuItem` objects, however UI objects can only have a single parent at a time, so your `MenuItems` can only exist in either your `ContextMenu` or your `ItemsControl`, and not both.

One possible option to do what you want is bind using a Converter, which will take the objects inside your `ContextMenu`, and make a copy of the `Icon` property, and return a collection of the images to display. It should be noted that this won't work until your `ContextMenu` is opened the first time because the `MenuItems` are not actually rendered until needed.

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyObjectWithContextMenu, 
    Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" />
```

where `MyConverter` takes the object passed to it, gets the object's `ContextMenu`, loops through each `MenuItem` in `ContextMenu.Items`, stores a copy of the `Icon` property in a `List<T>`, then returns the List.